# Using a reverse proxy/tunneling tool with nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an application on my local system which i want to use a reverse proxy on.
It had earlier showed me the nginx landing page but when i made some modification to the nginx configuration it no longer shows me anything neither does it show any error in the error log.
What I want to achieve are

1. My nginx page to show up on the remote url which is generated by the reverse proxy
2. I want the nginx to route all request made to localhost to a specific url which is generated from inside my local computer.

this is my nginx config

> default file

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

> mylocal.domainname.com.conf file

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

types {
# nginx's default mime.types doesn't include a mapping for wasm or wav.
    application/wasm     wasm;
    audio/wav            wav;
}
upstream app1 {
    zone upstreams 64K;
    server 127.0.0.1:5990;
    keepalive 2;
}
upstream app2 {
    zone upstreams 64K;
    server 127.0.0.1:1910;
    keepalive 2;
}
...........
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mylocal.domainname.com;

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    default_type "text/plain";
    root         /usr/share/local-app;
    }
    location = /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    return 404;
    }
    location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name mylocal.domainname.com;

    # Mozilla Guideline v5.4, nginx 1.17.7, OpenSSL 1.1.1d, intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers SOME-HIDDEN-CIPHER-DETAILS;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;
    set $prefix "";
    set $custom_index "";

    ssl_certificate /etc/local_app/mylocal.domainname.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/local_app/mylocal.domainname.com.key;

    root /usr/share/local-app;
.....

    index index.html index.htm;
    error_page 404 /static/404.html;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json image/x-icon application/octet-stream application/wasm;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied no-cache no-store private expired auth;
    gzip_min_length 512;

    include /etc/local_app/sub/*.conf;
......

    location ~ ^/_api/public/(.*)$ {
    autoindex off;
    alias /etc/local_app/public/$1;
    }

    # ensure all static content can always be found first
    location ~ ^/(libs|css|static|images|fonts|lang|sounds|.well-known)/(.*)$
    {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    alias /usr/share/local-app/$1/$2;

    # cache all versioned files
    if ($arg_v) {
        expires 1y;
    }
    }

..........

    # Matches /(TENANT)/aws-worker.js or /(TENANT)/manifest.json to rewrite to / and look for file
    location ~ ^/([^/?&:'"]+)/(aws-worker.js|manifest.json)$ {
    set $subdomain "$1.";
    set $subdir "$1/";
    rewrite ^/([^/?&:'"]+)/(aws-worker.js|manifest.json)$ /$2;
    }

................
```

currently the error log does not show anything even when the page is not showing not displayed.
It used to show error.

Please could be wrong with my configuration that is not making the remote url to work well. it used to show the nginx welcome page, but no  longer showing it.

2. secondly how can i cofig nginx so that all request to localhost or 127.0.0.1 loads the specific domain and still be showing be shwing 127.0.0.1 or localhst in the adress bar.